# Errors when creating thumbnails for large images in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm getting the following error in the log when MediaWiki tries to make a thumbnail of a large image in MediaWiki.  I've tried increasing the limits of various things like upload size but that doesn't seem to work.  What limit do I need to increase to get this to work?

```
/var/www/genwiki/bin/ulimit4.sh: line 4: 12338 File size limit exceeded'/usr/bin/convert' -quality 80 -background white -size 318 '/var/www/genwiki/images/b/b0/JamesGibsonSr_001.jpg' -thumbnail '318x599!' -depth 8 -sharpen '0x0.4' '/var/www/genwiki/images/thumb/b/b0/JamesGibsonSr_001.jpg/318px-JamesGibsonSr_001.jpg' 2>&1
```

Comment: Have you increased the size in the php.ini file?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, one of the files that's failing is a file that is < 2MB, which is the default max size for uploads in php.ini

Comment: One more question. Does your host have a restriction to file upload size? You can view this through phpinfo().

Comment: Yes, it's now 8MB, which is what I changed it to last.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to LocalSettings.php did the trick.  It's probably better to not use unlimited, but pick sane defaults instead of "unlimited".

```
$wgMaxShellMemory   = unlimited;
$wgMaxShellFileSize = unlimited;
```